# Monitor buffer size of Kotlin Flow

Tags: kotlin, buffer, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a complex chain of operators on a Kotlin Flow, and many of them are ran in groups in different contexts using `flowOn` like this:

```
flowOf(1, 2, 3)
    .map { /*do some stuff*/ }
    .flowOn(context1)
    .map { /*do some different stuff*/ }
    .flowOn(context2)
```

According to [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-on.html), each `flowOn` introduces a channel buffer with default size 64 (configurable).

In addition to this, I have a `MutableSharedFlow` with a fixed buffer size configured by the [`extraBufferCapacity`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow.html) parameter to which I'm emitting items.

I would like to monitor the current buffer sizes, however, the buffers are private property and there seems to be no method to retrieve the buffer reference or its current size. Is there any way to retrieve it, or is it intended solely for internal Flow purposes?